# How do I check whether the user has pressed ESCAPE or not?

Tags: python

```
#greenhouse monitor algorithm
import msvcrt
while not (msvcrt.kbhit() and .....): #I want to check whether the key pressed is <ESCAPE> or not
    sensor1=float(input("Please input the temperature of the green house: ")) 
    sensor2=float(input("Please input the oxygen level of the green house: "))

    if (sensor1>45):
        print("Warning. Temperature is too high")

    if (sensor2<0.19):
        print("Warning. Oxygen level is too low")
```

How do I check whether the key pressed is ESCAPE or not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653072/exiting-a-loop-by-pressing-a-escape-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use the [select](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/select.html) module (or [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/msvcrt.html#console-i-o) on Windows).